# set SoapAction http header for soap v1.1 from bpel process

Tags: web-services, soap, wso2, bpel, ode

I have a bpel process that calls a Microsoft web service. In the wsdl the soap action is defined on the operations. However when the bpel invokes the operation the http soapaction header property is set to "" and not the correct Acton for the operation. I can understand why you'd want this to be set to "" if there was no action set on the operation (to conform to the soap v1.1 standards) but wso2 business process server is not respecting the action set in wsdl.
Any ideas how to resolve this? Is there a setting to ensure the operation is used or alternatively how do I set it within the bpel? I can set the WS:addressing Action in the soapheader but it needs to be set to the same for Microsoft web services in the soapaction header property. I cannot proceed any further without resolving this. To be clear, the service itself works fine from soapui. 
Many thanks
Conrad

Comment: Are you sure that it is SOAP 1.0 and not 1.1/1.2? The former is from 1999 and only from Microsoft, the latter are published by W3C and are  frequently used.

Comment: Of course you are correct! It's v1.1 I am using. Edited original question to reflect this.